# apache kafka grep messages and write to file

Tags: apache-kafka

I have an apache kafka cluster and a topic mytopic. This topic contains messages in json format of the form:

```
{
"id":"77e345-lkjsdf345-aofs0345454",
"type_of_data":"57",
"version":"1.1",
"type_operation":97
}
```

I need to find messages with type_operation:100 and write to file myfile.
I am trying to search with the following command:

```
sh /kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer --consumer.config /kafka/consumer.conf --from-beginning --bootstrap-server 192.168.0.7:9092 --topic mytopic |grep "type_operation\"\:100"
```

The necessary messages are correctly filtered, but when I try to redirect this output to a file (command below), nothing is written to the file, the file is empty. If you remove the value 100 from grep and leave `grep "type_operation \" \:"`, then the messages are written to the file myfile.
What is the reason for this?

```
sh /kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer --consumer.config /kafka/consumer.conf --from-beginning --bootstrap-server 192.168.0.7:9092 --topic mytopic |grep "type_operation\"\:100" >myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your output is stuck in grep's output stdio buffer.  When you remove "100", grep produces more output so it finally exceeds the buffer size and is autoflushed to the file.  Try `grep --line-buffered "type_operation\"\:100"`, it should work.  It is not specific to kafka, any pipe where producer does not finish will behave this way.